# Can't save widget

Tags: widgets

I can't save widget. When I click save, I can see wait circle, and nothing happend. When I visit again widgets section, it's empty.

Then I changed view to Accessibility Mode, and still no luck.

Then I've changed `id` in functions, because that's the place where I create my widgets, and all those widgets I've tried to add before were in inactive widgets, but still can't save any.

Also theme doesn't show anythyng.

What can I do to make it work?

**UPDATE**

```
// add widgets
function iu_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'          => __('disp name', 'dev'),
        'id'            => 'footerBoxOne',
        'description'   => __('disp desc', 'dev'),
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  => '<h4><span class="title">',
        'after_title'   => '</span></h4>',
    ));
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'          => __('disp name', 'dev'),
        'id'            => 'footerBoxTwo',
        'description'   => __('disp desc', 'dev'),
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  => '<h4><span class="title">',
        'after_title'   => '</span></h4>',
    ));
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'          => __('disp name', 'dev'),
        'id'            => 'footerBoxThree',
        'description'   => __('disp desc', 'dev'),
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  => '<h4><span class="title">',
        'after_title'   => '</span></h4>',
    ));
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'          => __('disp name', 'dev'),
        'id'            => 'footerBoxFour',
        'description'   => __('disp desc', 'dev'),
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  => '<h4><span class="title">',
        'after_title'   => '</span></h4>',
    ));
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'iu_widgets_init');
```

of course `dev` is my theme slug. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Have you tried [turning on Debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee yes, I did, I didn't get any errors. I also turned off all plugins, but it didn't make any difference

Comment: @miszczu If you have no errors ( even in your `debug.log` file ) and you've turned off all plugins then the next step it to actually show your code. Tell us what each function does, what you expect to happen, where the code is saved, etc. Otherwise all possible answers will be guesswork.

Comment: do you want me to paste all `functions.php` file content?

Comment: Thank you all. I just took code from [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar), I've changed `footerBoxOne` to `footer-box-1` for all four widgets, and it's working now. Maybe uppercase chars were the problem

Comment: Indeed, you are right - make it an answer.

Comment: So obvious, we all missed it. Just goes to show how easy it is to miss something so obvious :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all. I just took code from [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar), I've changed id `footerBoxOne` to `footer-box-1` for all four widgets, and it's working now. I guess uppercase chars were the problem

Comment: `id` is actually a slug value. Slugs should always be lowercase and if it has more than one word, these words should be separated with hyphens only. As I said, very obvious but we all missed that. We all deserve that noddy badge :-). +1